# Thunderbird not fetching emails

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird is not getting emails at all! This has been happening for a few days now and I've only just realised! It sends emails OK but doesn't get any. I was using a slightly older version of Thunderbird, but I've updated to the latest version, version 115.0, the 32 bit version for Windows and the problem still persists. The only warning message I get in the developer console is:-

```
services.settings: Failed to load last_modified.json: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

Can anyone help me find out what's going on and to fix the problem.

Comment: According to https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/HG2KIk1EHgc , on upgrade, IMAP servers were lost. If you have a drive image, you could try to restore from the old profile. Otherwise, it seems IMAP settings for each account need to be recreated. Had it been a big gap between updates? Possibly a vital intermediate version was missed. See also https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1377355 on Apache.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: I hadn't updated Thunderbird for some time before the problem arose, I onlt updated after the problem happened to see if it would help - it didn't!

Comment: Found the cause, I was using the STARTTLS protocol, switching it to SSL/TLS fixed the issue. Maybe they've stopped supporting that protocol?